# Плавный ЗУМ при приближении кластера Yandex Map Api

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Использую API 2.1

Использую кластеризацию. И хотелось бы сделать плавный зум при нажатии. В google api приближение кластера происходит плавно.
В яндексе я использую

```
myMap.setBounds (geoObjects, {
            checkZoomRange: true
});
```

Приближение происходит мгновенно и получается что юзера просто бросает в какую-то область карты. Сбивает с толку. Есть ли решения для плавного перехода при приближении кластера?

Comment: Если актуально, скиньте, пожалуйста, полный код вашего примера. И обратите внимание, что по умолчанию setBounds анимируется только если разница между текущим и целевым коэффициентом зума ≤5 — изменить это можно в параметрах карты [options.maxAnimationZoomDifference](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.maxAnimationZoomDifference)